# Como funciona a arquitetura MVC + camada de Serviço?

Tags: php, java, mvc, services

To tentando encontrar alguma documentação para isso, se alguém tiver um livro que aborde o assunto favor informar.

Comment: Você quis dizer arquitetura MVC + camada de serviço?

Comment: sim to editando

Answer (score 0):

Nesse caso, a camada de serviço é interpretada como parte da arquitetura MVC (modelo-visão-controlador) e não como algo adicional.

A visão mostra ao usuário a interface e opções que ele terá, então, ao selecionar algo, o controlador decide como vai tratar o serviço e chama o modelo para atender o pedido do usuário.

Se o serviço é algo interno e você consegue incluir ele no controlador e/ou no modelo, é ali o lugar mais indicado. Se o serviço é externo, provavelmente seu controlador vai acessar ele como se fosse um modelo, mesmo que parte da lógica seja feita pelo serviço.

Por exemplo, se você tem um software do tipo SoA, ele tipicamente não inclui a parte da Visão. Para integrar um software SoA com um MVC, provavelmente o MVC vai usar o SoA como um modelo.